# New JavaFx library

Tags: javafx-2, fxml

I am using *Netbeans 7.2* and *JavaFX 2.1*. I want to make a library `mycompany.utils.sysuser` to maintain login information. This library can be used in many different app, with a JavaFX dialog for *login/logoff/change password*.

I don't know how to begin, a *regular Java library* or a new *JavaFX FXML application*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really matter.  The JavaFX project might generate some extra code and build tasks which you might or might not need but you can remove them if you need to or leave them be.  JavaFX is just another library so you're also OK with a java project, just add JavaFX as a dependency.

It is complete overkill and confusing IMO to have a project for FXML and a project for the java files.